# Commutator of Linear Operators Identities in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I would like an explanation about how commutator identities work.

I am doing Shankar's *Principle of Quantum Mechanics* book, and the first chapter is all about Linear Algebra. He gives to my hands the following commutator identities:

$$ \Omega \Lambda - \Lambda \Omega \equiv [\Omega, \Lambda]$$

$$ (i) \; [\Omega, \Lambda \theta] = \Lambda[\Omega, \theta] + [\Omega, \Lambda]\theta $$

$$ (ii) \; [\Lambda \Omega, \theta] = \Lambda[\Omega, \theta] + [\Lambda, \theta]\Omega $$

Let me say what I have understood from it.

$(i)$ The commutator between an operator and a product of two operators is equal to the commutator between the left side operator of the original commutator and the second operator of the right side, multiplied by the first operator of the right side of the original commutator, plus the commutator between the operator of the left side of the original commutator and the first operator of the right side of the original commutator, multiplied by the second operator of the right side of the original commutator.

$(ii)$ You should have got an idea what it should looks like from what I've written in item $(i)$.

What I have understood is correct? If not, what would be the correct interpretation of this identity? If yes, is there any other way to explain it simpler?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: saying it in words doesn't really simplify it, I think. Also, when you do decide to use words, you should watch out to specify on which side you are multiplying, since commutativity does not work in this context.

Comment: That's a translation from one language to another. Translation can be part of understanding. Maybe also note how the formulas are similar to Leibniz' product rule for the derivative: $D(fg)=fDg+(Df)g$.

Comment: Fair enough. Considering non-commutativity, the statement should be:
The commutator between an operator and a product of two operators is equal to the first operator of the right side of the original commutator, multiplied by the commutator between the left side operator of the original commutator and the second operator of the right side, plus the commutator between the operator of the left side of the original commutator and the first operator of the right side of the original commutator, multiplied by the second operator of the right side of the original commutator.

Comment: To what concerns using words, I just did it so you guys could understand how my mind is interpreting it, since it was not clear to me in symbols. But I agree that in symbols it should be simpler.

To what concerns the analog to the derivative formula, I still struggle to associate it with the operator's identity, cause I have 3 operators and when you showed me the derivative product rule there are only two functions.

Comment: If $[\Omega, \cdot]$ plays the role of $D(\cdot)$, $\Lambda$ the role of $f$ and $\theta$ the role of $g$, then $D(fg)=fD(g)+(Df)g$ is the same formula as $[\Omega,\Lambda\theta]=\Lambda[\Omega,\theta]+[\Omega,\Lambda]\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for showing me your translation, Lukas!
MoonLightSyzygy, now I have nailed it! That's really clarifying, thanks! What about the second statement? We can work out the same way?

Comment: @VictorLins Yes: the same idea applies if we say that $[\cdot,\theta]$ now plays the role of $D(\cdot)$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you guys a lot!